# Is there a way to attach a mirror to a piezoelectric?

Tags: piezoelectric

I want to use a mirror on the piezoelectric in Mickelson setup, how should I connect this?
Resonance frequency of piezoelectric is important for me. Is there a method to not change the frequency?

Answer (score 2):

Extra mass will change the resonance frequency. It would be minimal for an evaporated layer of aluminum (but the effect is large enough to be used for thickness monitoring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_crystal_microbalance ).